# Number input Angular: how to set a maxlength of a mantissa and characteristic of a number input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am writing a Validation code for a number Input in Angular 8. The decimal point must be fixed on the Input field. The input field gets a decimal number and the characteristic must has a maxlength of 5 and the mantissa a maxlength of 3 digits.

Is there any idea, how to do this in Angular?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make life easier you can split that input into two inputs with a "." in between,
then on the decimal input use Angular built-in validator:

```
max(99999)
```

cause the value can't be bigger than this for 5 digits.

the same goes for the mantissa input with :

```
max(999)
```

You can read more about Angular Validators here [Doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#max)